# Android failed to export application

Tags: android, failed-installation

I have problem when trying to sign my application in release mode from over two/three days now. I've tried everything which I find as an information in internet/stackoverflow and nothing worked for me. I've update my whole `SDK`, update `proguard` to 4.7 version, checked for jar files and conflict packages, but can't find any solution. I have included library to my main project,but 'till now I did not have any problems with signing my application.

Any ideas what else I can try so I can solve this problem, because I'm still reading some information over internet and still can't find any solution.

P.S. I did not have problem with building debug version and running on device. The only problem I get is only when I try to sign my application on release mode and I get `Failed to export application` error.

Comment: Do you already have an exported apk file in the destination folder? I find I have to delete previous versions otherwise I get an error.

Comment: Actually the destination where I'm saving my signed apk is my desktop, where I delete the old version everytime when I'm going to create a new one. So I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: I solved this problem by just restarting my machine ... may it help someone ..

Comment: Deleting `bin/` and `gen/` (and waiting for them to be re-created automatically) may help. At least it did for me.

Answer (score 8):

For me, the answer of Jmart was the good one.
You can easily have rotten file name in your project.

Whatever, I post an answer because, as Android-Droid I was stuck with the common message "Failed to export applicaiton".

But by trying to **export my app without signature** (see the screenshot under), this time **it gaves me explanation on the error !** Whereas it don't say anything when you sign with the wizard.

[image]

Hope it helps others like me !

Comment: +1 .. amazingly exported as unsigned gives an explanation of the error, normally resources with a bad name, ... without this trick you can spend hours looking for anything

Answer (score 4):

Believe it or not... I had the same problem ('android failed to export..' without any other indication/message). After many many hours I found the problem: I had a .jpg resource under the assets folder with some special characters (ilíaco.jpg). Just removing the "offending" character and problem solved.

Comment: This is not a specific error, the asker is looking for all the causes of `Failed to export application`, not just one cause.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same with a 'ö' in a png-file-name.

Answer (score 3):

You have some errors, I would say. Try to run the app on the virtual machine to see if it works. if it works, try to clean and rebuild the project and then export.. worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Have you created your own certificate to sign the app for release? Don't use the debug certificate automatically generated by Eclipse because you won't be able to sign your app for update later (especially if you export your project on another computer).

If so, has your certificate expires? Do you provide the good passwords?

Comment: Actually till now I've signed my application so many times and never had a problem. I have my own keystore and I'm pretty sure it's not expired. Still can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

http://simply-developing.blogspot.in/2013/08/eclipse-failing-during-android-export.html

try this i searched all these questions and only the above link solved my problem, i had failed to export dialog without errors

Answer (score 1):

What I did was export unsigned it first then export signed. It worked, never knew what caused it though.

Answer (score 1):

For me "Clean" and then run "Export" again - solved it

Answer (score 0):

I have heard about using @+id in attribute like layout_below, layout_above etc.. can cause this problem check this out. use this only in android:id="@+id/idid" cases.

Comment: As a matter of fact I'm using `layout_below="@+id/id_of_elem"`  a lot,but never give me that kind of error before. It's my (maybe) 50th signing of my app.

Comment: ADT version up causes the problem I heard. I experienced this issue in real.

Comment: to above cases use @id/ instead of @+id/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enough space on your OS hard drive!

I have a small SSD for my Windows drive, and I use other drives for my applications/data.  Which had plenty of space, my SSD had only a few Mb left on it (hadn't done a clean in a while).

Turns out Eclipse was writing temp files to AppData/Local and didn't have enough space to store them - causing the ridiculously generic error "Failed to export application"

Answer (score 0):

I had some boostrap plugins that contained .swf files. They wore never used or requested. 
Only after I deleted them it worked.

To be always sure: keep only image+css,html,js files and it will never give the weird error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by running the application in emulator once - found the error (in my case it was looking for a asset sub folder)

Fixed the error, ran it in Emulator successfully - then Exported the APK file.

Hope this helps.